# Why are my goblins panicking for no apparent reason?

Tags: goblin-camp

Recently, I've noticed that my goblins have been panicking around a lot and interrupting their jobs. At first I thought it might be because they get really hungry or something, but I checked the [Goblin Camp Wiki](http://goblincampwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Status_Effects#Panic), and it said that it's because they saw an enemy. I can narrow down it down to the bottom right side of my camp, but  I checked around, and I don't see any enemies on the map. Why's this happening?

Pic included:

[image: My crazy goblins getting scared of nothing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treeman, perhaps. Looks the same as a tree.

Comment: Really? Then that's very possible, although my orc squad also panicked when I sent them around there. Sadly, I deleted all my old saves after I upgraded to v1.41 that they were incompatible with, so I can't look for them. :(

Comment: Wait! My saves were still in the recycle bin! I looked around more and they all seemed normal when I moused over them, and sent a couple squads walking around around there.